# Send POST data with raw json with postman Express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, postman

I'm trying to log all the data and then return it as a response.

```
app.post('/data', (req, res) => {
  const data = req.body
  console.log(data)
  return res.json({
    data
  })
})
```

I'm sending data with Postman. In the Body tab I have "raw" selected and "JSON (application/json)". Headers tab is Content-Type application/json. I'm sending this:

```
    {
      "aa": 23
    }
```

When I click send button all I get is an empty object and the data variable is undefined in my console.log. How to fix it? I double checked everything. It should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: Did you install middleware to handle post request data, such as body-parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're passing an invalid value to res.JSON(). Try:

```
return res.json(data);
```

Comment: Not necessarily, perfectly valid JS property shorthand

Comment: Now I got nothing in Body and data variable is still undefined in console.log.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I found the solution.

"As body-parser module is used to parse the body and urls, it should be called before any call to 'req.body...'."

So I did this:

```
import bodyParser  from 'body-parser'

const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded())
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/data', (req, res) => {
  const data = req.body
  console.log(data)
  return res.json({
    data
  })
})
```

And now it works fine.